# Call the same function for all rejected promisses

Tags: javascript, angularjs, request

I want to do the same thing for all promisses in case of error. How can I refactor my code to achieve the same result but with no repeated code?

```
$rootScope.syncing = false;
$scope.syncError = true;
```

My promisses:

```
Users.updateAuth().then(function(auth) {
    Interests.syncAll().then(function(interests) {
        Events.syncAll().then(function(events) {
            $rootScope.syncing = false;
        }, function(error) {
            $rootScope.syncing = false;
            $scope.syncError = true;
        });
    }, function(error) {
        $rootScope.syncing = false;
        $scope.syncError = true;
    });
}, function(error) {
    $rootScope.syncing = false;
    $scope.syncError = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you return a Promise inside a Promise's `then` callback, that promise is used for the `then` chain:

```
Users.updateAuth().then(function(auth) {
  // do something with auth
  return Interests.syncAll();
}).then(function(interests) {
  // do something with interests
  return Events.syncAll();
}).then(
  function success(events) {
    // do something with events
    $rootScope.syncing = false;
  },
  function failure(error) {
    $rootScope.syncing = false;
    $scope.syncError = true;
  }
);
```

Comment: That worked! Now I'm trying to get notify message for each step but nothing happens. Look how I'm doing, following your logic: `Users.updateAuth().then(function(auth) {
      return Interests.syncAll();
    }).then(function(interests) {
      return Events.syncAll();
    }).then(
      function (events) {
        $rootScope.syncing = false;
      },
      function (error) {
        $rootScope.syncing = false;
        $scope.alerts.push({
          type: 'danger',
          msg: error
        });
      },
      function (message) {
        $rootScope.syncing = message;
      }
    );`

Comment: I also addd deferred.notify with a message right before each request.

Comment: I got it, just wrap in a timeout function and notify will works; Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted you could:

```
function error() {
    $rootScope.syncing = false;
    $scope.syncError = true;
}
```

And then call that in each of the 3 places.

My apologies if this is exceedingly obvious and not what you're looking for.

I don't know a better way off the top of my head.

Promises typically have an "always" you can use for when you want something to happen regardless of a success or failure, but I don't think that applies to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Promises are chainable. You can use catch on the last promise in the chain.

```
Users.updateAuth().then((auth)=>{
   //do something with auth here
   return Interests.syncAll()
}).then((interests)=>{
    //do something with interests
    return Users.updateAuth();
}).then((events)=>{
     //do something with events
     $rootScope.syncing = false;
}).catch((err)=>{
     //catch any error here
    $rootScope.syncing = false;
    $scope.syncError = true;
   console.log(err);
});
```

**Note:**

I used the arrow function here in this snippet. In case, you dint know, its just a short form for bound anonymous functions. 
`()=>{}` is actually `function(){}.bind(this);` Just a short form. function(){} without bind would work here just fine, since we are not using the this reference.